# request.session.user is undefined on the express-graphql context

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm building an app which is using Node/Express and Graphql. We are using this module for graphql-server-express and also we are using express-session to maintain our user into our request.session. Everything was working fine until when we started thinking about protecting our queries (user needs to be authenticated before consulting).

Our design is working flawlessly when we are using Graphiql, however, inside the application, the session simply doesn't contain the user logged in. Already debugged plenty of times and the user is present on the session, but GraphQlExpress keeps saying it is not. Below is my configuration:

```
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress(request => ({
schema,
context: { user: request.session.user })));
```

After login, my express session is set this way:

```
const user = employee.dataValues;
      request.session.user = user;
```

Everything works nicely, except when I try to consult the graphql context, which doesn't contain the user in the session:

```
allCandidates: {
type: new GraphQLList(CandidateType),
resolve(_, args, context) {
  return protect(context, () => Candidate.findAll());
}},
```

Again, the route /graphiql works nice. But /graphql doesn't. My client side is using React with Apollo Graphql

Would you guys have any inputs?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds weird, probably not coming from `express-graphql`. Can you post the protect function code?

Comment: Hi @whitep4nther... the protect function is simply this:

`const protect = (context, ...fn) => flow([isAuthenticated, ...fn])(context);`

All I'm doing is to use a Lodash 'Flow' function to handle all my function calls in order. However, the problem is inside the resolve function. The context attribute is undefined, so my protect function will always think the user is not authenticated. Didn't find a good way to solve it yet :(

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, have you found a solution yet?